# Failed to register window when using local WNDCLASSEX variable

Tags: variables, winapi, global, local, registerclass

If I put the `WNDCLASSEX wcex` variable definition out of main function (as global variable) the class will be registered successfully

```
#include <windows.h>
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
int main()
{
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.lpszClassName = "Success" ;

    if ( !RegisterClassEx ( &wcex ) )
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL, "Failed to register window class.", "Error", MB_OK );
    }
}
```

But If I put it inside the main function, It will not be registered

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof ( WNDCLASSEX );
    wcex.lpszClassName = "Success" ;

    if ( !RegisterClassEx ( &wcex ) )
    {
        MessageBox ( NULL, "Failed to register window class.", "Error", MB_OK );
    }
}
```

I can't figure out the reason, kindly help in this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Objects with static [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) are zero-initialized<sup>1)</sup>. Your second example is semantically different in that `wcex` (automatic storage duration) holds random values. To match the semantics, use `WNDCLASSEX wcex = { 0 };` instead.

---

<sup>1)</sup> *Assuming you are using a C++ compiler. The rules for C are different.*

Comment: For C, use `memset()` or `ZeroMemory()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I was referring to the rules for initialization of objects with static storage duration. Those are zero-initialized in C++, but I don't know C well enough to know the rules there. I believe that C doesn't mandate any initialization, and when using C, both `wcex` structures would be uninitialized, and contain random values.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thank you, But can you tell me why does RegisterClass funtion refuses the (random-values) WNDCLASSEX variables ?

Comment: @Mostafa36a2: I suppose the `RegisterClassEx` function performs parameter validation. When passing in garbage, the *style* member can easily be dismissed as invalid. Likewise, the *lpfnWndProc* must point to valid, executable memory. This, too, is easily verifiable, since it needs to correspond to the *hInstance* value. The bottom line is: The second example exhibits undefined behavior, and it's usually not very interesting why it fails.

Comment: ...why is the first example even working with a `NULL` `lpfnWndProc`?! It's a good thing it didn't, as otherwise this problem would have been masked, but still.

Comment: @andlabs: Apparently you can register a window class without a window procedure (or rather, the call to `RegisterClassEx` doesn't fail). I don't know how a window of that class would behave, though.